# ASP.NET MVC Core Error -> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I know there are a few questions of this error posted but none of them helped me!
I'm using ASP.NET MVC Core and Identiy and I'm trying to update Roles. But it's getting a bit nerve wrecking because I can't find out what's the problem with my code.

The error is the following:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

[screen of the error is display here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxZrl.png)

**My controller:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
{

    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    //var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    var role = await roleManager.Roles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == id);

    if (role == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(role);

}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("Id,Name")] IdentityRole role)
{
    if (id != role.Id)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        try
        {
            _context.Entry(role).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await roleManager.UpdateAsync(role);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

        }
        catch (DbConcurrencyException ex)
        {

            throw new DbConcurrencyException(ex.Message);
        }


    }
    return View(role);
}
```

**My View :**

```
    @model Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Roles</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
       
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

I would really appreciate some help getting this error fixed.

Comment: Hi whether you want to update from app role or database role

Comment: I have a class named Person with some properties and this class is derived from IdentityUser. What do you think should be the solution?

Comment: the link may help you  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct. replace this:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([Bind("Id,Name")] IdentityRole role)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var roleItem = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(role.Id);
                if (roleItem != null)
                {
                    roleItem.Name = role.Name;

                    var updateResult = await _roleManager.UpdateAsync(roleItem);
                    if (updateResult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Handle errors
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Handle errors
                }
            }
            return View(role);
        }
```

Comment: your code generated the following error: 

InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'IdentityRole' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap<TKey>.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)

Comment: i mean the variable name in my code. yous hould update roleItem variable

Comment: I've managed to solve the issue by adding a ViewModel. Thanks!